# Prove: $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \log\frac{1}{x} dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{9}{(3n+4)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove the following:

$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \log\frac{1}{x} dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{9}{(3n+4)^2}$

I think that I need to use function series and convergence theorems but I don't even know from where to start? Could someone help me or give me a hint?

Comment: Hint $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k\ge 0}x^{k}$ if $|x|<1$.

Comment: @RAHUL's hint is especially easy to exploit by substituting $u:=-\ln x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \log\frac{1}{x} dx=- \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \log(x) dx$$

Note that $ \displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} x^t = \log(x)$. Hence, by Fubini-Tonelli we can interchange derivative/limit and integral sign:

$$I = - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \log(x) dx  = - \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/3}}{1-x} \left(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} x^t \right)dx = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{1/3+t}}{1-x}dx$$

Now expand $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x}$:

$$ I = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} -\int_{0}^{1} x^{1/3+t}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} dx$$

Again, by Fubini-Tonelli:

$$ I = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1/3+t+n}  dx = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+t+\frac{4}{3}} =   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0+}\frac{-1}{n+t+\frac{4}{3}}\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{1}{\left(n+t+\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{9}{\left(3n+4\right)^2}$$

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0+}x^t=log(x)$ true? I know that $\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0+}x^t=ln(x)$ but can I put $log$ instead of $ln$ ?

Comment: @User160 Yes, it is assumed that $\ln(x), \log_{e}(x), \log(x)$ denote the natural logarithm if you do not specify the base explicitly.